# Copy the query of GET to clipboard

Tags: javascript, php, html

Is it possible to copy the query of a form, which is using GET method, to the clipboard?

[image: Link]

My aim is to have a button, which when pressed should copy the value in the black box to the clipboard so it is easily shared with someone else.

**Edit**: Not just asking about copying something into the clipboard, I am also asking about how to get the value of the GET query..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I copy to the clipboard in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript)

Comment: @Ele No it is not. I want to get the value of a **GET query** to the clipboard

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: Because I am asking about how to get the value of the query not just how to copy to the clipboard

Comment: Regex will be the wae.

Comment: what do you mean by the black box..What is it??

Comment: @Uzair Did I upload the photo incorrectly? https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fp26W.png

The blackbox contains the "website"/"php file"?"Value of GET" and I want to copy the whole thing into the clipboard. Or if that's not possible to a text field where the user can copy it themselves.

Answer (score 2):

The GET parameters are only added to the submitted URL at the moment where the button is pressed, i.e. the form is submitted, so I don't think that 's possible directly (i.e. retreiving a value from the submit button)

But you could use a plugin like https://clipboardjs.com/, "collect" all the form data via JS and combine them together with the initial URL for its return value including the GET data.

Comment: Ah, though it would be easy. However, thanks for the link I will see if I can get it to work the way I want it to!

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
var path = location.href.replace(/[^\?]+$/,$('form').serialize());
var cpy = $('input#cpy').val(path);
    cpy.select(); 
    document.execCommand('copy');
```